# Java throws out an exception where I think it shouldnt

Tags: java, exception, crash, try-catch

```
System.out.println("\nHow many sticks do you want?");
    while(sticks==0){
        try{
            sticks=startInput.nextInt();
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            sticks=0;
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number.");
        }
        sticks=startInput.nextInt();
    }
```

What I try to do:
It asks for an int but when someone types in chars it should ask again instead of crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `sticks=startInput.nextInt();` is not within the `try-catch` block, thus if you place more characters it will fail again. Since you are not handling the exception yourself, the exception will bubble up and eventually crash your application.

EDIT: As per your comment, it depends. Assuming that you want to close your application when/should the user provide `0` as an answer to your question, you could do this:

```
System.out.println("\nHow many sticks do you want?");
    while(sticks >= 0){
        try{
            sticks=startInput.nextInt();
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            sticks=0;     //Any value which is not 0 will not break your loop. This will be re-populated when the user will supply the number again.
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number.");
        }
    }
```

If you want your application to *stop* (which seems less likely) from your code:

```
System.out.println("\nHow many sticks do you want?");
    while(sticks==0){
        try{
            sticks=startInput.nextInt();
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            sticks=0;     //The 0 will break your while loop, exiting your application gracefully.
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number.");
        }
    }
```

This is something which works:

```
private static int sticks;
    private static Scanner startInput;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sticks = 0;
        startInput = new Scanner(System.in);        
        while (sticks >= 0) {            
            try {
                System.out.println("How many sticks do you want?");
                sticks = Integer.parseInt(startInput.nextLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                sticks = 0;     //Any value which is not 0 will not break your loop. This will be re-populated when the user will supply the number again.
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid number.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay and how do I fix it?

Comment: Remove the second line

Comment: @TheEisbaer: I have updated my answer. Should you have further queries let me know.

Comment: @JamesHutchinson: Just removing the second `sticks=startInput.nextInt();` will make the application exit gracefully, which I do not think that is something which the OP is after. I presume he/she would like to keep asking the user until a satisfactory input is provided.

Comment: Sorry i think is explained myself a bit bad. I try to do it like this: The program asks the user to type in a number, the user doesnt type in a number because he misclicked, then the program should ask again. With your first solution my program still quits or do I have to have something after it?

Comment: @TheEisbaer: Sorry my bad... I have made some minor modifications, which should solve your problem (first example). Please let me know if it does not.

Comment: Okay then it starts spamming "Please enter a valid number." and does not ask the user again.

Comment: @TheEisbaer: It does not ask the user again because the question is being asked from outside the loop. Moving it within the while loop should fix that. With regards to spamming, I do not understand. Your code should hold at `sticks = startInput.nextInt();` since that is a blocking call. So unless you keep providing incorrect values, then it shouldn't trash your console.

Comment: Well I do it in BlueJ, and it just ignores the next time because, it says sticks = null (http://puu.sh/goPxp/2711481f6e.png)

Comment: @TheEisbaer: How are you initialzing the scanner?

Comment: @TheEisbaer: Did you declare the `sticks` variable? Such as `int sticks = 0`?

Comment: Yes in a constructor `public test(){
        int sticks=0;
    }`

Comment: @TheEisbaer: If that is the case, then `sticks` only exists within the constructor. You will need to move that line (`int sticks = 0;` either in the method you showed me or else set it up as a class variable.

Comment: Okay, did that. Didn't change the outcome of skipping the input.

Comment: @TheEisbaer: If I am understanding you correctly, it should not have compiled before since the `sticks` variable did not exist in the proper scope. Can you provide me with a complete view of the class?

Comment: http://puu.sh/goQUY/b5e2b99e1c.txt that is my whole class in BlueJ
-
Or http://puu.sh/goQXK/f88ab33097.txt this in eclipse

Comment: Okay a friend of mine fixed it by putting `startInput.nextLine();`in the catch.
I thank you very very very much for your help and time :)

Comment: @TheEisbaer: I have uploaded a working version. For some reason, `nextInt` kept getting invoked regardless of the input, I would presume that printing values was what was causing the issues. The code I posted should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing to put a loop in here, check below code :

```
while(true){
    System.out.println("\nHow many sticks do you want?");
        while(sticks==0){
            try{
                sticks=startInput.nextInt();
            }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                sticks=0;
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid number.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I don't type in a number then it starts spamming "please enter a valid number." but it should ask the user that once and then the user should type a number again.

Comment: Suppose you want the user to get n (say 3 ) number of attempts before terminating, you can do this as below :  
    int attemptNum = 0;
while(attemptNum<3){
     attemptNum++;
    System.out.println("\nHow many sticks do you want?");
        while(sticks==0){
            try{
                sticks=startInput.nextInt();
            }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                sticks=0;
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid number.");
            }
        }
    }